# MySQL Workbench generate tables from EER Diagram

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I am using MySQL Workbench and created an EER Diagram with several classes, columns, relationships, etc... now I have been looking and wondering if it is possible to let this application auto-generate these tables in my database? Up until now I haven't found it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try **File -> Export -> Forward Engineer SQL Create Script**. Here you can generate the SQL Script corresponding to your EER diagram, and execute this script in your database engine.

Answer (score 1):

check out this tutorial from the MySQL website,[HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-create-connection.html) and [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html) it shows how to create a connection between Workbench and the server and after that you can forward engineer any tables and such into a database. Hope it's what you're looking for.:)

Answer (score 0):

**Database > Forward engineer...** is a wizard who will guide you to the creation of the database you have modeled.

Comment: Is this an update to [PierreF's 2014 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23041548)? Did the menus change, or is this option available in both? (Which version?)